# uploading static files of django app to s3 with boto3 and storages

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto3, django-staticfiles

I know that this question has been asked a lot of times but i still can't get it to work. My Env configuration:

- Python 2.7
- Django 1.9.5

In my requrements.txt i have the following dependencies

- boto3==1.4.2
- django-storages==1.5.1

I have added the `storages` in my INSTALLED_APPS. These are my settings parameters.

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='****'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='****'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME='****'
AWS_AUTO_CREATE_BUCKET = False
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE
AWS_LOCATION = 'static/'
```

When i run the `./manage.py collectstatic` command i get the following error:

```
File "/home/me/myproj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto.py", line 23, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Could not load Boto's S3 bindings.\n"
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not load Boto's S3 bindings.
See https://github.com/boto/boto
```

Any ideas why? what didn't i configure properly?

Comment: I have the same issue. This error was solved when I ran pip install boto. The [django-storages-documentation](http://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html) states the following: Another for interacting via Boto3 was added in version 1.5. Unfortunately I do not really understand what this statement should mean. And I assume that django-storages will use boto instead of boto3 when both versions are installed.  It is unclear to me as well how to configure django-storages to explicitely use boto3 instead of boto.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I was writing the comment I finally figured out the solution: 
in your settings.py use:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

instead of:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
```

There is also an open issue on the libary for better documention regarding boto3:
https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/issues/229

I found the solution in the source code of django-storages that you can find here: 
https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/blob/master/storages/backends/s3boto3.py

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the django-storages code (https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/blob/master/storages/backends/s3boto.py), this error is thrown when django-storages can’t complete `import` statements to `boto`.  My guess is that you are using a really, really old version of boto.  Try upgrading `boto` to version 2.40+ with:

```
pip install boto==2.44
```

Comment: Thank you - Your solution would solve the problem - i was looking for a boto3 solution. If i am using boto3 there is no real reason to use boto for this specific thing.

Answer (score 0):

Since, `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'`

You have to install boto

`pip install boto`

Comment: Thank you - Your solution would solve the problem - i was looking for a boto3 solution. If i am using boto3 there is no real reason to use boto for this specific thing.